# Best practice for archiving g-suite domain email

Tags: outlook, g-suite, archive

Looking for some input on best practices for archiving a google domain email with Outlook(2010/2013) as the software being utilized on the EU side. To this point we have a few users that have much higher inbox size/count that is causing major issues with slowness. With those users we have been archiving the emails when they start to slow down. Just wondering what everyones recommended practices as far as outlook data file size, email count, etc are to make the email sync/run more efficiently as we have limited control over the server side with this being a google domain.